# how sort with mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

I have a little question
I try to sort with mongoose I know the simple way
but I dont know how to do that with data I get in req.body lets say.
I add here a code I try

```js
exports.sortBy = async (req, res, next) => {
    const data1 = req.body.data1 //the data i want to sort
    const sortBy = req.body.sortBy //sory by price,createdAt,length and more
    const downUp = req.body.downUp // 1, -1
    console.log(sortBy)
    console.log(data1)

    const data = await Book.aggregate([
        {
            $sort: { [sortBy]: downUp }
        },
    ])

    res.status(200).json({
        status: 'success',
        results: data.length,
        data
    })
}
```

so I  can sort by the data I get in req.body

Comment: I am confused, what is data1 used for? And why does the `.aggregate` not have a `$match` to query the collection?

Comment: you right I need to explain myself better. so data1 is array of object(result of search), so I want to take to search results(data1) and sort him. About the aggregate it because I think is the only way to do sort I know with mongoose maybe there is another option to do a sort with mongoose without aggregate?

Comment: Still confused. If you get the data from the client, and want to sort it, then send back to the client, why not sort in the client in the first place?

Comment: 2 reasons.  1 Because if i sort in the front and save it in the state when i refresh the page or something rendering the component my data lost. reason 2 is Because with mongoose is much easy

Comment: You can use browser localStorage or sessionStorage to cache data locally

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```js
const data = await Book.sort({sortBy: downUp});
```

which seems to work and is much easier to read.

Comment: this is no what I want here is search for all the book data and sort but whet i want is just the data i send to the back-end to sort. i do a search and i want to sort the results i get from the search  i do search => send the result to the back-end => sort the results => send back to the client